# Get the ID of 10 Latest Pages stored in a Wordpress Category

Tags: categories, pages

How Do I get the ID of latest 10 pages from a certain category in my wordpress blog. Please suggest me a relevant function to get that in a form f array or something that could give me the ID's of latest 10 pages of my blog.

Comment: Do you mean get the latest 10 posts from a category?

Comment: no I mean latest 10 pages from a category. My wordpress blog has Page Categories as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below. This is the Reference: [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'category_name' => 'mycat',
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
$data = get_posts($args);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Remember, `cat` takes an integer value, not the category slug

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. edited the code

Comment: I have changed your code a bit to use the `fields` parameter to just return an array of ids. This is way faster, and is exactly what the OP wants. Please check my edit. Also, if a parameter is set to default value, you don't need to write it out. It wastes space and time :-)

Answer (score 0):

please try this for latest pages.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'category'         => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
);
$data = get_posts($args);
print_r($data); ?>
```